# Function and variable trouble

Tags: python, function, variables

I have recently started using python and I am having trouble with my code. Basically, my code is supposed to generate 10 random equations that are additions. The problem I am having is that the the Real_Answer variable will not recognise the User_Answer even if it has the right answer, it always says it is wrong even if it is right..help!

```
def Random_Num():
 a = random.randint(0, 20)   #Random number between 0 - 20
 return a



def Ending(Real_Answer, Counter):
    if User_Answer == Real_Answer:
        print ("That is correct well done!")
        Counter = Counter + 1
    if User_Answer is not Real_Answer:
        print ("That is the wrong answer! The answer is", Real_Answer)

Counter = 0
i = 0
Name = input("What is your name?")
for i in range(0,10):
       Random_Num()
       Number_Add = Random_Num()
       Number_Again = Random_Num()
       print("The equation is", Number_Add, "+", Number_Again)
       Real_Ans = Number_Add + Number_Again
       int(Real_Answer)
       User_Answer = input(str("What do you think the answer is?"))
print("That is the end of the 10 questions")
print("Overall, you got ", Counter," out of 10!")
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but the opposite of `==` is `!=`, not `is not`.

Comment: what is int(Real_Answer) supposed to to? I think you need a User_Answer = int(User_Answer) to change a string into an integer.

Comment: Is that your whole code?

Comment: There are many problems in this code. As an example, `Random_Num()` in your _for loop_ has no effect at all. Same goes for `int(Real_Answer)`; it either has no effect, or even worse, causes NameError. `i = 0` not used (_for loop_ doesnt need it).                  Checking a tutorial might be very helpful, so i highly suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing `Real_Answer`, an integer, to `User_Answer`, a string, you're never going to find that they're equal. `User_Answer = int(input('What do you think the answer is?'))` is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def Ending(Real_Answer, Counter):
    if User_Answer == Real_Answer:
        print ("That is correct well done!")
        Counter = Counter + 1
    else:
        print ("That is the wrong answer! The answer is", Real_Answer)
```